# mvn test leads to NoClassDefFoundError though it is in the class path

Tags: java, maven, jar, jena, xerces

some explanation on the project first. I'm building https://github.com/paulhoule/infovore/tree/v1.1.1 and having problems with maven. However this only happens on a Debian 3.2.57 machine, while it works on a Ubuntu 13.04 machine. This is why I'm not filing an issue with the related projects but would rather like to know ways to debug this.

Several tests fail on  `mvn test` because of the same `ClassDefNotFoundError`. Some excerpts from the surefire reports:

```
 <error message="org/apache/xerces/xs/XSTypeDefinition" type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/xs/XSTypeDefinition
    at com.ontology2.millipede.triples.PartitionOnSubjectTTest.testBin(PartitionOnSubjectTTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/xs/XSTypeDefinition
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.n3.turtle.ParserBase.<init>(ParserBase.java:25)
    at com.ontology2.rdf.parser.NodeParser.<init>(NodeParser.java:337)
```

However the corresponding jar is in the classpath as `mvn test -X` shows:

```
[DEBUG] test classpath classpath:
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/tools/infovore-1.1/millipede/target/test-classes
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/tools/infovore-1.1/millipede/target/classes
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-arq/2.9.3/jena-arq-2.9.3.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-core/2.7.3/jena-core-2.7.3.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-iri/0.9.3/jena-iri-0.9.3.jar
--> [DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.10.0/xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar**
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.5/commons-codec-1.5.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.2/httpclient-4.1.2.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.3/httpcore-4.1.3.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.4/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar
[DEBUG]   /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

And a look in the corresponding jar reveals that the class is indeed in there:

```
jar tf  /home/semmul2/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.10.0/xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar | grep XSTypeDefinition
>> org/apache/xerces/xs/XSTypeDefinition.
```

The corresponding pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>infovore</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.ontology2</groupId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.ontology2</groupId>
  <artifactId>millipede</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>millipede</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
      <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

After a suggestion from Rob Hall I've also tried putting one of the failing tests into the jar and executing the test code as a main function. This is the result:

```
java -cp millipede-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.ontology2.rdf.parser.NodeParserTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/xs/XSTypeDefinition
        at com.hp.hpl.jena.n3.turtle.ParserBase.<init>(ParserBase.java:25)
        at com.ontology2.rdf.parser.NodeParser.<init>(NodeParser.java:337)
        at com.ontology2.rdf.parser.NodeParserTest.main(NodeParserTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.xs.XSTypeDefinition
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 3 more
```

I've already tried:

- Removing the complete local repository to avoid conflicts with other projects
- Explicitly adding the xerces dependency
- Compared the maven and java versions as well as environment variables to the working machine

Any other ideas are much appreciated! :)

Comment: On the failing machine it is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 on the passing machine it is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

Comment: Have you tested whether the version of xerxes being pulled actually contains the class that is requested? You could have a newer/older version of xerxes that is not compatible with all the items that have a dependency on it. Maven will exclude all but one instances of a transitive dependency if your direct dependencies depend on different versions. In eclipse m2e, you can view your transitive dependencies to see if a version is being excluded. You can also explore the jar itself through project explorer to validate that the class is present.

Comment: You're not explicitly stating the compiler plugin version, so the maven runtime is using a default value. Could it be a bug in a particular platforms distribution of maven? What does `mvn --version` say for each of the two target platforms? Can you grep for `maven-compiler-plugin:` on your build output so we can also see the invoked compiler version?

Comment: As a note, I've verified that `jena-arq:2.7.3` depends on `jena-core:2.9.3` which depends on `xerxesImpl:2.10.0`. Given the reported jars above, we can confirm that there doesn't appear to be any skewed versions for the transitive dependencies.

Comment: Can you run a non-test class without getting this error? for example, if you were to copy your test to your `src/main/java` folder and change the test method to be a `public static void main(String...)` instead, do you still get this error? Going out on a limb, it may be the case that there is a bug in a particular compiler plugin version that results in excluding transitive dependencies from the test classpath.

Comment: thanks for all those ideas! I'm very sorry however, but I can only access the faulty machine on Friday morning again, so I can only try them then.

Comment: So first of all I've tried to execute the test code in a main function. Again it leads to a `NoClassDefFoundError`. I've added the complete stack trace to my answer.

Comment: The maven versions are: 3.0.4 on both machines. The compiler plugin version is 2.0.2 on both machines.

Comment: One additional information for completeness to give you a full picture: This project is a submodule of another project, so there is a parent `pom.xml`. However this only specifies the modules and sets the compiler source and target version to 1.7. Anyway, if executed from the parent project exactly the same error occurs.

Comment: All I can think of at this point is to test the newest version of maven instead ([3.2.1 Download](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)) if it's possible. Updating beyond `3.1-alpha-1` requires that your plugin versions are changed as well ([source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound)). If that doesn't work, there has to be something we're missing.